# settings from PreferenceActivity not saved after app restart

Tags: android, preferenceactivity

my settings activity extends `PreferenceActivity` and everything's working as expected as long as I stay in the app. But as soon as I restart the app (e.g. via the Android Studio), all settings are back to default.

I also tried to set the `isPersistent` flag, doesn't help either.

example of an entry in settings.xml:

```
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:defaultValue="false"
            android:key="askcode"
            android:title="@string/askCodeSettingsString" />
```

`onCreate` method from my subclass:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
    ...
```

that's how I try to fetch the setting when restarting the app:

```
 SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
 boolean keepdata = pref.getBoolean("askcode", false);
```

I also read that some people got it working by changing their entry in `AndroidManifest.xml` but that looks good to me:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light" >
    </activity>
```

***EDIT***

other preferences I'm storing manually are working as expected:

save:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit();
editor.putString(PREFS_MANUAL, "12345");
editor.commit();
```

fetch:

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    String myString = prefs.getString(PREFS_MANUAL, "");
    return myString; // now 12345
```

***EDIT 2 ****
It seems I have found the problem - but not what's causing it. I have default values for all my preferences; for the strings it's `android:defaultValue=""` I guess that's not enough, but how can I prevent this?

```
09-18 12:13:23.763      925-940/com.... W/SharedPreferencesImpl﹕ getSharedPreferences
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Map value without name attribute: string
        at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.readThisMapXml(XmlUtils.java:568)
        at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.readThisValueXml(XmlUtils.java:821)
        at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.readValueXml(XmlUtils.java:755)
        at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.readMapXml(XmlUtils.java:494)
        at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.loadFromDiskLocked(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:113)
        at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.access$000(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:48)
        at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$1.run(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:87)
```

Comment: Never had these problems. Your code sure looks like it should work. Are you sure you're not re-installing the app thus clearing the data?

Comment: are you committing your preference editor with values ?

Comment: @DoctororDrive yes, I'm sure - please see my edit.

Comment: @JibranKhan no - where/how do I have to do that?

Comment: Your code looks ok. You are having problems fetching the boolean value right ?

Comment: Are you similarly doing this editor.putBoolean("askcode", true); ? before committing.

Comment: I'm neither doing some ```putBoolean``` nor some kind of committing in that class

Comment: So you should add putBoolean similarly to how you are putting the strings.

Comment: but how, where and when? In the examples I found this wasn't necessary

Comment: just add it before editor.commit();

Comment: I do not have ```editor.commit()``` - look e.g. at http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-preferences-activity-example/ or http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/09/preferenceactivity-in-android-example.html - there are no ```editor.commit()``` as well

Comment: @swalkner, you are correct. @JibranKhan probably isn't familiar with the persistent `Preference` usage.

Comment: @swalkner I wonder how do you kill the app. Have you tried exiting the settings screen normally (by back button or home then recents swipe out). My bet is if you kill the app through `DDMS` while `PreferenceActivity` is opened, it will not save because the saving is done asynchronously.

Comment: @DoctororDrive I already did exit the ```PreferenceActivity``` normally. When I enter it again, the settings are as expected. But if I restart the app through ```DDMS```, everything is reset.

Answer (score 1):

The `PreferenceManager` calls [apply()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply()) which saves the preferences to persistent storage asynchronously.

So my guess is when you kill the app through DDMS the preferences are not yet written.
When you tried saving manually you've called [commit()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#commit()), which blocks UI thread until the preferences are written to persistent storage.

In the code snippet whre you tried saving it manually, If you call [apply()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply()) instead of `commit()`, you will get the same result as using the `PreferenceScreen` logic.

When I first asked if you are quitting the `PreferencesActivity` normally I thought maybe it initiates write in `onStop()` or `onDestroy()` event etc, but it turned out that it's not related much.
I'm not familiar with the internal logic of `apply()` that much to say how much time you should wait before the preferences are written, but it shouldn't take a long time.

There is nothing to worry about. The apps are not normally killed like that when running on end-user device.

If you are concerned about preferences not being saved immediately, the only way is setting [OnPreferenceChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener.html) on every [Preference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html) you want to be saved immediately and writing the value to the `Editor` calling `commit()` on preference change event.

If you do that, remember to set `android:persistent="false"` on every preference you've saving manually so it will not run automatic saving in background again.